# Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("String.sub / Bytes.sub")

Tags: ocaml

I am learning OCaml and working my way through the advent of code 2022.

But it seems that reading the `input.txt` file is causing some issue.

```
A X
B Y
C Z
```

I am getting this strange error, that comes from the func `score`. Particularly the expression call `scorer hd`. Though, when I manually set the `lines` variable to a `list string`, everything works.

The error occurs here inside the func `scorer`:

```ml
    | hd :: tail -> score_helper tail scorer (scorer hd + acc)
```

```ml
let read_lines filename =
  let contents = In_channel.with_open_bin filename In_channel.input_all in
  String.split_on_char '\n' contents

let lines = read_lines "input.txt"

let score input scorer =
  let rec score_helper input scorer acc =
    match input with
    | [] -> acc
    | hd :: tail -> score_helper tail scorer (scorer hd + acc)
  in
  score_helper input scorer 0

(* Gets called on every row, returns the score value *)
let scorer s =
  let theirs =
    match String.sub s 0 1 with
    | "A" -> "X"
    | "B" -> "Y"
    | "C" -> "Z"
    | _ -> assert false
  in
  let ours = String.sub s 2 1 in
  let played =
    match ours with "X" -> 1 | "Y" -> 2 | "Z" -> 3 | _ -> assert false
  in
  let result =
    match (theirs, ours) with
    | "X", "Y" | "Y", "Z" | "Z", "X" -> 6
    | theirs, ours when theirs = ours -> 3
    | _ -> 0
  in
  played + result

let () = Format.sprintf "Part 1: %d" (score lines scorer) |> print_endline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is revealed by inspecting `lines`:

```ml
# lines;;
- : string list = ["A X"; "B Y"; "C Z"; ""]
#
```

Note the last element: `""`! You most likely want to ignore this empty line.

A simple way to handle this case is to ignore this blank lines in the `score` function:

```ml
let score input scorer =
  let rec score_helper input scorer acc =
    match input with
    | [] -> acc
    | "" :: tail -> score_helper tail scorer acc
    | hd :: tail -> score_helper tail scorer (scorer hd + acc)
  in
  score_helper input scorer 0
```

Comment: @bennouli incidentally, if that helps you, to find out what the problem is, I loaded the code into an interactive toplevel, then I `#trace scorer` and I executed the driver code. It showed that `scorer` was called four times, the last one with the empty string.

Comment: Thanks that's actually very helpful. Did you just copy paste the code into the "utop" REPL with a `#trace scorer` before the execution of the the functions?

I'm trying to find better ways to debug, this is actually a good start.

Comment: @bennouli yes, but you could have done that with a regular file and `#open "file.ml"` or having a text editor that is capable of handling toplevels.

Comment: You might also simply remove all of the empty lines before processing: `let lines = List.filter ((<>) "") @@ read_lines "input.txt"`  This might be adapted to detect any line which doesn't conform to an expected format.

Answer (score 1):

[jthuhlu has identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071413/15261315) the source of your problem.

However, there is another way to approach your problem. Your `score` function transforms a list into another value. As such, this is a perfect place to use a fold.

```
let score input scorer =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun i x -> 
       match x with
       | "" -> i
       | _ -> scorer x + i)
    0
    input
```

Now, if we don't need to look for `""` values because we've filtered them out, this can be simpler.

```
let score input scorer =
  input 
  |> List.fold_left (fun i x -> scorer x + i) 0
```

We can incorporate filtering into this.

```
let score input scorer =
  input
  |> List.filter ((<>) "")
  |> List.fold_left (fun i x -> scorer x + i) 0
```

Now, for large data samples, iterating the whole list and creating a new list with `List.filter` may be onerous, so we can use sequences instead.

```
let score input scorer =
  input
  |> List.to_seq
  |> Seq.filter ((<>) "")
  |> Seq.fold_left (fun i x -> scorer x + i) 0
```

Comment: I wish standard library functions returned sequences instead of lists (or at least had a sequence counterpart) so that you wouldn't have to choose between efficiency and not reimplementing `String.split_on_char` or things like that. Otherwise, avoiding useless intermediate lists is really painful.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

My `input.txt` actually had empty lines, which caused the `String.sub` in the `scorer` function to crash the program. I added a fallback case for an empty string to the function:

```ml
let scorer s =
  let len = String.length s in
  if len < 3 then
    0
  else 
  let theirs =
    match String.sub s 0 1 with
    | "A" -> "X"
    | "B" -> "Y"
    | "C" -> "Z"
    | _ -> assert false
  in
  let ours = String.sub s 2 1 in
  let played =
    match ours with "X" -> 1 | "Y" -> 2 | "Z" -> 3 | _ -> assert false
  in
  let result =
    match (theirs, ours) with
    | "X", "Y" | "Y", "Z" | "Z", "X" -> 6
    | theirs, ours when theirs = ours -> 3
    | _ -> 0
  in
  played + result
```